# Function composition and its representations

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I wonder:

1) are the following functions exactly the same:

```
inc = (+1)
double = (*2)

func1 = double . inc
func2 x = double $ inc x
func3 x = double (inc x)
func4 = \x -> double (inc x)
```

2) why doesn't `func5` compile?

```
func5 = double $ inc        -- doesn't work
```

Comment: The dot operator `(.)` is used to "pipe" functions together, so that the expression `f . g` is a **function**, where the result of `g` is used as an argument to `f`. The dollar operator `($)` is used to give arguments to a function, so that the expression `f $ x` is a **value**, where `x` is given as an argument to `f`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Are these functions exactly the same?

Actually, no! There are some very subtle differences. First of all, read about the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). In short, class-polymorphic functions are given different types by default if they're "obviously" functions or not. In your code, this difference won't manifest, because `inc` and `double` aren't "obviously" functions and so are given monomorphic types. But if we make a slight change:

```
inc, double :: Num a => a -> a
inc = (+1)
double = (*2)

func1 = double . inc
func2 x = double $ inc x
func3 x = double (inc x)
func4 = \x -> double (inc x)
```

then in ghci we can observe that `func1` and `func4` -- which are not "obviously" functions -- are given a monomorphic type:

```
*Main> :t func1
func1 :: Integer -> Integer
*Main> :t func4
func4 :: Integer -> Integer
```

whereas `func2` and `func3` are given a polymorphic type:

```
*Main> :t func2
func2 :: Num a => a -> a
*Main> :t func3
func3 :: Num a => a -> a
```

The second slight difference is that these implementations may have (very slightly) different evaluation behavior. Since `(.)` and `($)` are functions, you may find that invoking `func1` and `func2` requires a little bit of evaluation before they can run. For example, perhaps the first invocation of `func1 3` proceeds like this:

```
func1 3
= {- definition of func1 -}
(double . inc) 3
= {- definition of (.) -}
(\f g x -> f (g x)) double inc 3
= {- beta reduction -}
(\g x -> double (g x)) inc 3
= {- beta reduction -}
(\x -> double (inc x)) 3
```

whereas the first invocation of, e.g, `func4 3` gets to this point in a much more straightforward manner:

```
func3 3
= {- definition of func3 -}
(\x -> double (inc x)) 3
```

However, I wouldn't worry about this too much. I expect that in GHC with optimizations turned on, saturated calls to both `(.)` and `($)` get inlined, eliminating this possible difference; and even if not, it's going to be a very small cost indeed, since this will likely happen only once per definition (not once per invocation).

> Why doesn't `func5` compile?

Because you don't want it to compile! Imagine it did. Let's see how we would evaluate `func5 3`. We'll see that we "get stuck".

```
func5 3
= {- definition of func5 -}
(double $ inc) 3
= {- definition of ($) -}
(\f x -> f x) double inc 3
= {- beta reduction -}
(\x -> double x) inc 3
= {- beta reduction -}
double inc 3
= {- definition of double -}
(\x -> x*2) inc 3
= {- beta reduction -}
(inc * 2) 3
= {- definition of inc -}
((\x -> x+1) * 2) 3
```

Now we are trying to multiply a function by two. At the moment, we haven't said what multiplication of functions should be (or even, in this case, what "two" should be!), and so we "get stuck" -- there's nothing further that we can evaluate. That's not good! We don't want to "get stuck" in such a complicated term -- we want to only get stuck on simple terms like actual numbers, functions, that kind of thing.

We could have prevented this whole mess by observing right at the beginning that `double` only knows how to operate on things that can be multiplied, and `inc` isn't a thing that can be multiplied. So that's what the type system does: it makes such observations, and refuses to compile when it's clear that something wacky is going to happen down the line.

Comment: fantastic answer! (with meticulous precision in reduction sequences, great introduction of the type system, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

1) Yes.  Those functions are all absolutely identical

2) To see why `func5` doesn't work, just expand out its definition:

```
func5

-- Definition of `func5`
= double $ inc

-- Definition of `($)`
= double inc

-- Definition of `double`
= 2 * inc

-- Definition of `inc`
= 2 * (1 +)
```

The compiler is complaining because `(1 +)` is a function, and you can't double a function.

Comment: To the OP: there is a perfectly natural notion of doubling a function into a commutative ring (which numbers are supposed to be).  It's just not possible using Haskell's broken numeric typeclasses.  You can hack around this by defining
    `instance Num b => Num (a -> b) where
      f + g = \a -> f a + g a;
      f * g = \a -> f a * g a;
      fromInteger = const . fromInteger;
      -- ...`
and then double $ inc will do what you expect.

Comment: @Fixnum Actually, you can double any function into an abelian group: `(2 * f)(x) = f(x) + f(x)`.

Comment: @Joker_vD - Actually, you can double any magma-valued function (with some loss of good properties).  I'm sorry for not generalizing my answer fully :)  With a module structure you can multiply by ring elements (if you hack up more instances), not just integers, which is probably what the OP expects.  You're perfectly right, of course.

Answer (score 4):

The first four functions are identical.

---

You are trying to apply `double` to `inc`. This won’t work, as `inc` cannot be multiplied.

```
double $ inc
-- is the same as
double inc
```

If you add type specs you’ll see it:

```
inc :: Integer -> Integer
double :: Integer -> Integer
```

`double` takes an `Integer` but you are trying to pass it an `Integer -> Integer`.

Note that it is good practice to explicitly state the types of top-level functions in Haskell, as these often tell a lot about the functions and the program.

Answer (score 3):

`$` (called the apply operator) is not a different way of writing `.` (function composition operator). You can see that they are not the same by using *ghci*:

```
>:t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b

:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

You can always substitute `$` with parentheses. So `func2` and `func5` can be rewritten as:

```
func2 x = double (inc x)
func5 = double (inc)
```

But `double` expects a value of type `Num a => a` and you are passing it a value of type `Num a => a -> a` that's why it doesn't work.

You can read more about `$` [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application), and about `.` [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition).